# App works locally but not on heroku, not using mongo and all my dependencies are in package.json

Tags: node.js, heroku

My app works locally but heroku gives me an error. heroku logs --tail gave me this...

```
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.60.2 to 7.65.0.
2022-10-27T00:25:20.296932+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user daniloffraf97@gmail.com
2022-10-27T00:25:20.296932+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user daniloffraf97@gmail.com
2022-10-27T00:25:20.442762+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user daniloffraf97@gmail.com
2022-10-27T00:25:20.442762+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user daniloffraf97@gmail.com
2022-10-27T00:26:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user daniloffraf97@gmail.com
2022-10-27T00:28:31.548779+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 65404edd by user daniloffraf97@gmail.com
2022-10-27T00:28:31.548779+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user daniloffraf97@gmail.com
2022-10-27T00:28:31.564573+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user daniloffraf97@gmail.com
2022-10-27T00:28:32.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-10-27T00:28:34.830414+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-10-27T00:28:36.583178+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
2022-10-27T00:28:36.583253+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-10-27T00:28:36.583337+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
2022-10-27T00:28:36.583513+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
2022-10-27T00:28:36.583632+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
2022-10-27T00:28:36.583675+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-10-27T00:28:36.583715+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
2022-10-27T00:28:36.583760+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!   npm run
2022-10-27T00:28:36.585354+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-10-27T00:28:36.585513+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2022-10-27T00:28:36.585566+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-10-27T00_28_36_547Z-debug-0.log
2022-10-27T00:28:36.701365+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-10-27T00:28:36.832817+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-10-27T00:28:36.836786+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-10-27T00:28:40.221680+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-10-27T00:28:41.962372+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
2022-10-27T00:28:41.962440+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-10-27T00:28:41.962505+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
2022-10-27T00:28:41.962659+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
2022-10-27T00:28:41.962759+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
2022-10-27T00:28:41.962792+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-10-27T00:28:41.962822+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
2022-10-27T00:28:41.962855+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!   npm run
2022-10-27T00:28:41.964441+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-10-27T00:28:41.964580+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2022-10-27T00:28:41.964623+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-10-27T00_28_41_918Z-debug-0.log
2022-10-27T00:28:42.081849+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-10-27T00:28:42.160578+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-10-27T00:31:55.028584+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=damp-meadow-65132.herokuapp.com request_id=682b9314-d3c3-4483-933b-b349ee3e3e73 fwd="173.56.4.208" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-27T00:31:55.192929+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=damp-meadow-65132.herokuapp.com request_id=92d6d28e-ac5d-4e63-bc0a-ce489b8f6494 fwd="173.56.4.208" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
^C
rafaels-MBP:NovaCapital rafael$ 
rafaels-MBP:NovaCapital rafael$ heroku config
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.60.2 to 7.65.0.
=== damp-meadow-65132 Config Vars
```

All my dependencies are in the son file. I am not using mongoose as this is a simple website.

Can someone please help? Ty

I tried to find the problem but couldn't...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stopping Heroku from running npm start + what to run instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167753/stopping-heroku-from-running-npm-start-what-to-run-instead) There's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65685493/im-facing-a-heroku-doployment-problem-npm-start-not-working) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55932106/react-missing-script-start#55932212). Most likely you don't have an `npm start` in your package.json and need to either add that, or change (or add) your Procfile.

Comment: Thank you! I didn’t realize that I even needed npm start. In hindsight it make sense though…